# Calculating element width in JavaScript gives wrong results

Tags: javascript, css

There is a simple `div` in the document with some styles. Its `width` is not set in HTML nor in CSS. I tried to calculate its actual width in JavaScript using different methods:

- `offsetWidth`
- `clientWidth`
- `getBoundingClientRect().width`
- `getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('width')`

but none of them returned the actual width which can be seen in Chrome Developer Tools.

Here is a code that demonstrate this issue:

```js
var resumeHeader = document.querySelector('#resume-header');
var resumeHeaderComputedWidth = getComputedStyle(resumeHeader, null).getPropertyValue('width');
console.log(resumeHeaderComputedWidth)
console.log(resumeHeader.offsetWidth);
console.log(resumeHeader.clientWidth)
console.log(resumeHeader.getBoundingClientRect().width)
```

```css
#resume-header {
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #F5D061;
        padding: 2px 6px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 14px;
        position: relative;
        top: 25px;
        left: 0;
        transition: width 1s ease;
        font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
        line-height: 1.8;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="resume-header">
    Resume
</div>
```

Please note that in the above snippet, the calculated width is sometimes correct and sometimes wrong, while in Chrome, it is always wrong.

Comment: Have you tried `innerWidth` and `outerWidth`? :)

Comment: Aren't they `window` properties? How can I use them in this case?

Comment: They are also jQuery functions that can be used on any element to get the height with/without margin, border etc. Ref: [innerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/innerwidth/) and [outerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/)

Comment: I am using plain JavaScript on my web page. I don't want to add jQuery overhead, especially that the problem can be solved without that :)

Comment: However, I am interested in knowing whether they solve the problem.

Comment: It was just a suggestion, which is why I only added it as a comment rather than an answer. But you had listed every other width, so I thought you might like to go for the full set :)

Comment: Yes, why not? :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## The Problem

It seems that sometimes the JavaScript code that calculates the width is executed before the web page is ready and the layout is calculated; I think that not setting the `width` property in the CSS file causes this issue.

## Solution

So the solution is to wrap the JavaScript code in an event listener on `window` that listens for `"load"` event:

```js
addEventListener("load", function () {
    var resumeHeader = document.querySelector('#resume-header');
    var resumeHeaderComputedWidth = getComputedStyle(resumeHeader, null).getPropertyValue('width');
    console.log(resumeHeaderComputedWidth)
}
```

#### Safari Case

However, this doesn't work with Safari due to its way of loading and displaying web pages. To work around this, add this line of code before the event listener described above:

```js
window.scrollBy(0,1);
```

More info on this behavior of Safari and its workaround: [Here](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/safaribenchmarks.html).

## Working Code

Here is the code with the above fixes:

```js
window.scrollBy(0,1);
addEventListener("load", function () {
    var resumeHeader = document.querySelector('#resume-header');
    var resumeHeaderComputedWidth = getComputedStyle(resumeHeader, null).getPropertyValue('width');
    console.log(resumeHeaderComputedWidth);
    console.log(resumeHeader.offsetWidth);
    console.log(resumeHeader.clientWidth);
    console.log(resumeHeader.getBoundingClientRect().width);
});
```

```css
#resume-header {
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #F5D061;
        padding: 2px 6px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 14px;
        position: relative;
        top: 25px;
        left: 0;
        transition: width 1s ease;
        font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
        line-height: 1.8;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="resume-header">
    Resume
</div>
```

Note: This solution has been tried on Chrome, Safari, and Chrome for mobile.

Comment: good response, becose in fiddle always give'm same value https://fiddle.jshell.net/ahketzLq/